# Spring boot 2.1.13.RELEASE hateoas links response is different from Spring boot 1.5.14.RELEASE hateoas links response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

We are upgrading our spring boot project from 1.5.14.RELEASE to 2.1.13.RELEASE. Everything is working fine except the hateoas links response.

For 1.5.14.RELEASE, the response is:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "urn:eim:linkrel:config": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/v1/config"
        }
    }
}
```

For 2.1.13.RELEASE the response is:

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "urn:eim:linkrel:config",
            "href": "http://localhost:3000/v1/config",
            "hreflang": null,
            "media": null,
            "title": null,
            "type": null,
            "deprecation": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any fallback way to get response as in 1.5.14.RELEASE?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 1.5 depends on Spring HATEOAS 0.23.

Spring Boot 2.1 depends on Spring HATEOAS 0.25.2.

Most of the fixes and improvements for Spring HATEOAS have been on the 1.0/1.1, which are supported by Spring Boot 2.2 and 2.3.

Due to all the structural changes made on 1.0, little to no changes are being backported to 0.25.x.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found the answer in this link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#mediatypes.hal.curie-provider

By adding this annotation @EnableHypermediaSupport(type= {HypermediaType.HAL}) on the configuration file, I am able get the links response the way I want.